# Как можно подключиться к базе данных "название" с помощью команд языка SQL?

Tags: sql

Как можно подключиться к базе данных "название" с помощью команд языка SQL?

(Срезовая работа, а что-то туплю)

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Тип и версия СУБД? откуда надо подключаться?

Comment: Вот и я о том же, я прям весь вопрос переписал

Comment: подключаетесь вы к серверу СУБД. а базу данных можно выбрать. команды SQL к подключению отношения не имеют, а вот для выбора БД на сервере обычно используется команда `use dbname;`

Comment: Тогда вопрос не имеет смысла. Вернее, он в принципе не имеет общего решения, на него не существует общего ответа. Скажем, в MySQL достаточно простой команды USE, а вот в Firebird или SQLite необходимо создавать новое соединение...